# Does field level security affect list view criteria?

Tags: list-view, formula-field, bug, platform-bug, field-level-security

**Question**

Is it true the field level security of a field used in the criteria for a list view is ignored? Or is this a bug?

**Background**

I created a new formula field that's true if a user lookup on the a record matches the current user and then used this to create a list view.  However when I logged in as a user who didn't have visibility to that field the filter wasn't applied.  Making the field visible to their profile fixed the issues.

Have I been drinking crazy juice and this is expected behavior or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user naturally has access to all of these records (presumably) and you're using the formula field to narrow the scope of the record display a bit more... (correct?)

So, the list view rather than showing zero records (because of the FLS + filter criteria) falls back to showing the user what they *can* see, which is an unfiltered list.

Comment: So you're saying it's intended behavior that salesforce just skips any criteria that use fields the running user doesn't have visibility to?

Comment: Yes. From a security perspective this is the correct approach. Imagine if the filter criteria was instead `Employees WHERE Salary > $200,000` - you may not have granted the running user with the ability to see employee salaries but that information could be gleaned from the results.

Comment: On a related note, the same feature regarding FLS and record filtering applies to reports and dashboards as well. I was surprised the first time I encountered this, but as @MarkPond explained the security model makes sense.

Comment: That's a good point about the salary, but in most of these cases I feel like the sharing model of the person creating the list view/report should apply.  From my perspective a lot of fields used for filtering fall into the "system" category and it would be a lot simpler for end users if they never knew they existed.

Comment: Initially it looked weird but now it make sense. However do we have any official documentation or response from SFDC on this?

Comment: Wait...
@MarkPond If user don't have FLS over Salary, then he won't be able to create/view criteria like this, right? Hence Admin can create criteria using salary but end user won't even know about that. Hence no data exposed. right?